# What will be the output of printf("%s",*&*str); where in str is a pointer?

Tags: c

this was the code snippet asked for me in a interview and pls explain me what is the use of *&*.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char *str="INCLUDEHELP";
printf("%s",*&*str);
}
```

Comment: *&*str is effectively *str, which is str[0] i.e, first character of str array but you are attempting to print it as a string when it's just one char without NULL terminator. If you would have used %c instead it would have printed first character 'I'

Comment: Are you *sure* the interview question used `%s` to print the result?

Answer (score 2):

The `&*` is an empty operation. The `&*str` (or like `&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*str` or any number of `&*`) is equivalent to just `str`. See [C11 note102](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note102). We can omit it.

```
char *str="INCLUDEHELP";
printf("%s", *str);
```

This code with `%s` is invalid. The `%s` expects zero terminated `char` array. The `*str` is a `char` with the value of `'I'`, a character. The program on linux-like systems will most probably receive a segmentation fault signal, because `'I'` will be an invalid address of a zero terminated character array.

If it were:

```
char *str="INCLUDEHELP";
printf("%c", *str);
```

or:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char *str="INCLUDEHELP";
printf("%c",*&*str);
}
```

, then the program would print a single character `I` on it's `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

The output is most probably the segfault.as it is the Undefined Behaviour.  The `&*...`  from the right mean. Dereference the pointer, get the address of the dereferenced  char, and dereference this address again passing the char instead of the pointer to printf.